# How to get ID for multiple selection image files input

Tags: jquery, image, forms, input

Im trying to get an ID for each image from multiple selection (input type=file) in order to delete them later.

```
function readURL(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();
    var imgn = 0;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        imgn ++;
        image.src    = e.target.result; 
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,     
                s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
             $('#imgpre').append('<p id="imgnum'+imgn+'"><img src="'+ this.src +'" width="80px">'+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+'<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeimg('+imgn+');"></p>');
             }  
             image.onerror= function() {
                alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
             }
       }
}
```

I have all my code working fine, only missing the ID of each image.
Using "imgn++" but im always getting number 1 for all images selected.

How to give unique ID for each one?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Declare `imgn` outside of that function, like:

```
var imgn = 0;

function readURL(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image  = new Image();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        ...
```

Otherwise every time that function runs it sets it back to 0, which with `imgn++` would always give you 1.

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Doing that Im getting the number of files selected